# unattended install and sql statements in postgres

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a shell script that install postgres and then afterwards run a couple of sql statements. i've tried to follow many tutorials, but keep getting `peer authentication failed for user postgres`? so far i have following shell script which install correctly but sql is not being executed.

```
# postgres install
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib

# edit configs and restart
sudo echo "listen_addresses = '*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
sudo echo "local   all             postgres                                md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
sudo service postgresql restart

sudo -u postgres psql postgres
echo "CREATE USER test WITH LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB     NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;"
echo "ALTER user postgres WITH PASSWORD '$PASSWORD';"
```

Answer (score 0):

several points to start with here:

1. when you echo `local...` to the end of `hba.conf` it is most often useless - first rules apply - you never reach that string. so better `sed`peer to md5 for the existing line if you really want local to connect using `md5`
2. you expect local socket connection for postgres to use md5 - it means you have to save password to `.pgpass` or enter it manually (which makes scripting useless)
3. `echo "CREATE USER ...` after `psql` wont work - ether save sql and call it with `psql -f file.sql` or run

`psql <<EOF`

`create user ...`

`...`

`EOF`

Comment: okay and how do i return to `root` user after `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`

Comment: that depends - what's you script?

Comment: i script an post installation script that install multiple applications.